# Get the column names for each index(row) such that column value is imposed upon some condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5], 'b':[4,0,6]})
>>> x
   a  b
0  1  4
1  3  0
2  5  6
>>> required = {0:['b'],1:['a'],2:['a','b']} ---> how to get it from x??
#keys -> index of x 
#values -> list of col names such that value is >2
```

How can we do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner using `apply` and `to_dict` methods.

```
In [162]: (x > 2).apply(lambda y: x.columns[y.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1).to_dict()
Out[162]: {0: ['b'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b']}
```

Details

```
In [173]: (x > 2)
Out[173]:
       a      b
0  False   True
1   True  False
2   True   True

In [174]: (x > 2).apply(lambda y: [y.tolist()], axis=1)
Out[174]:
0    [[False, True]]
1    [[True, False]]
2     [[True, True]]
dtype: object

In [175]: (x > 2).apply(lambda y: x.columns[y.tolist()].tolist(), axis=1)
Out[175]:
0       [b]
1       [a]
2    [a, b]
dtype: object
```

---

Here's *another* one-liner.

```
In [205]: {i: x.columns[y.tolist()].tolist() for i, y in (x > 2).iterrows()}
Out[205]: {0: ['b'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b']}
```

Or

```
In [122]: {i: y[y].index.tolist() for i, y in (x > 2).iterrows()}
Out[122]: {0: ['b'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b']}
```

Comment: 1 more thing. `x.columns[y.tolist()]` why does this raise error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` While `x.columns[y.tolist()].tolist()` doesn't?

Comment: This extremely perfect :)
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ideas which are efficient:

```
pd.DataFrame(x.columns.where(x > 2, ''))
Out: 
        0
0   (, b)
1   (a, )
2  (a, b)

np.where(x > 2, x.columns, '').T
Out: 
array([['', 'a', 'a'],
       ['b', '', 'b']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about efficiency but works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5], 'b':[4,0,6]})
a = defaultdict(list)
for b,c in df.iterrows():
    for d in c.iteritems():
        if d[1]>2:
            a[b].append(d[0])
print dict(a)
```

Output:

```
{0: ['b'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b']}
```